# AngularJS sample code showing code not data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm trying to follow a tutorial for MEAN stack starting with Angular and even the provided sample code won't work. The code shows instead of the data, eg. "{{created_buy}}" instead of "David". I'm new to Angular so I feel like I might be missing something obvious...

main.html:

```
<!--main.html-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chirp</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/chirpApp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="chirpApp">
<div id='main' class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <form ng-Submit="post()">
                <input required type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" ng-model="newPost.created_by" />
                <textarea required class="form-control" maxlength="200" rows="3" placeholder="Say something" ng-model="newPost.text"></textarea>
                <input class="btn submit-btn pull-right" type="submit" value="Chirp!" />
            </form>
            <div id="post-stream">
                <h4>Chirp Feed</h4>
                <div class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'created_at':true" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
                    <p>{{post.text}}</p>
                    <small>Posted by @{{post.created_by}}</small>
                    <small class="pull-right">{{post.created_at | date:"h:mma 'on' MMM d, y"}}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
//chirpApp.js
var app = angular.module('chirpApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

    $scope.post = function(){
        $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
        $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
        $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer the correct js file

```
 <script src="javascripts/chirpApp.js"></script>
```

but you have mentioned app.js, so it should be

```
 <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TaXBbYmT3pl7mKaZHn0g?p=preview)

Comment: The answer was even dumber than that, but that essentially what I did wrong, thank you! Was in javascript not javascripts

Comment: 3 letters vs 1 letter, just makes it that much more mundane. Note there is a time limit on marking as answer, which I have now done